# javaee 5 bookstore sample to run with jboss 4.0 and hibernate

Tags: java-ee-5, jboss-4.0.x

when i am trying to deploy bookstore1 web application from Netbeans ( JavaEE5 sample ) , i have changed the persistence.xml file to use hibernate :

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="book" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/BookDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.sun.bookstore.database.Book</class>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and my `mysql-ds.xml` file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources> 
    <local-tx-datasource> 
        <jndi-name>jdbc/BookDB</jndi-name> 
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookdb</connection-url> 
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class> 
        <user-name>root</user-name> 
        <password>1234</password> 
        <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
            <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource> 
</datasources>
```

I am getting below error:

```
[STDOUT] Couldn't create bookstore database bean: null
19:16:53,846 INFO  [[/bookstore1]] Marking servlet ShowCartServlet as unavailable
19:16:53,846 ERROR [[ShowCartServlet]] Allocate exception for servlet ShowCartServlet
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Couldn't get database.
        at com.sun.bookstore1.servlets.ShowCartServlet.init(ShowCartServlet.java:39)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
19:17:17,534 INFO  [[ShowCartServlet]] Servlet ShowCartServlet is currently unavailable
```

Can you please let me know where i am making wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss 4.0.x is not a JavaEE5 appserver, it's much too old - it only supports J2EE 1.4

This may not be the problem (it's impossible to tell from the info you've given us), but there's no point continuing with the JavaEE5 sample and JBoss 4.0.x, it just won't work.

You either need to use the J2EE 1.4 sample app, or upgrade your JBoss (to version 5 or 6).